# What table is the media's sort order stored?

Tags: media, sort, table

I see that your can sort media by a numbered order in the media gallery for a post.  But what table is this order stored in?  I want to use this order to also order the images the same way in my posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `menu_order`.

You can sort by multiple values too.

```
// Example
'orderby' => 'title menu_order'
```